# Bypass first time Plink hostkey verification via PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, ssh, putty, plink

I have written a script as below

```
$ipAddress = "10.10.10.10" 
$username = Get-Content -Path "path to user name"

$password = Get-Content -Path " path to password"

$hostkeyF="aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff:gg:hh:JJ:kk:"

# Define the path to the Plink executable

$plinkPath = "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe"

$sshCommand = "& '$plinkPath' -batch -ssh -hostkey $hostkeyF $username@$ipAddress -pw $password"

Invoke-Expression -Command $sshCommand
```

When I run it in PowerShell ISE I get error

> Host key did not appear in manually configured list

What I am trying to do is create a PowerShell script which connects to a remote device later I will improve it.

But issue is I want all the user to use this code present in my network hence I want to bypass first time hostkey verification.

Sorry if I sound confusing
Let me know if you need any other details

Please note that I cannot install any new module to solve this as it is restricted.

I have OpenSSH and Plink with me to work on this.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

With OpenSSH, you can use `accept-new` mode.

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new example.com
```

---

Plink does not have an equivalent functionality. All it supports is explicit specification of hostkey fingerprint using the [`-hostkey` switch](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-hostkey).